# Find the number of unique pairs in an array where one number is the other after swapping two digits

Tags: python, arrays

Find the number of unique pairs in an array where one number can be created by swapping two digits of the other number.

In the following array for example, there are three unique pairs.

```
arr = [3,23,156,4324,324,651,165,32] 
(32,23), (156,165), and (651,156)

output: 3
```

Note that 165 and 651 is not a pair because the problem only allowed a swap of two digits

The question should be done in less than O(n^2) time, what is a way to approach this question?

So far I am able to find the anagrams with the following code, but I think I'm already exceeding the time limit.

```
from itertools import combinations
# Online Python - IDE, Editor, Compiler, Interpreter
arr = [3,23,156,4324,324,651,165,32] 

def swapdigits(arr):
    same_length = []
    a = list(combinations(arr, 2))
    

    for i in a:
        if len(str(i[0])) == len(str(i[1])):
            char_frequency = {}
            for j in str((i[0])):
                if j not in char_frequency:
                    char_frequency[j] = 0
                char_frequency[j] += 1
            for k in str((i[1])):
                if k in char_frequency:
                    char_frequency[k] -= 1
                    if char_frequency[k] == 0 and i not in same_length:
                        same_length.append(i)

    return same_length

print(swapdigits(arr))
```

edit:
so I am able to get the anagram combos in a better way but I still can't get the swapping digits part, can someone point me to the right direction?

```
from itertools import combinations

def swapdigits(arr):
    same_length = []
    a = list(combinations(arr, 2))
    anagram = []
    

    for i in a:
        elements = [int(x) for x in str(i[0])]
        count_a = 0
        count_b = 0
        if len(str(i[0])) == len(str(i[1])):
            for j in range(len(str(i[1]))):
                second_num = str(i[1])
                if int(second_num[j]) == elements[j]
                    count_a += 1
                    if count_a == len(elements):
                        anagram.append(i)


    return anagram

print(swapdigits(arr))
```

I also tried the following to match the indexes of the anagrams and see if the same number has the same index except for two but it only works for particular cases...

Comment: This looks like a homework. Heave you tried anything so far? Please post any code you have. SO is not a homework solution service. **Hint**: you can try **Python**'s **itertools**'s **combinations** to get pairs and then check pairs for being anagrams of one another.

Comment: Also have a look here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: It is not a homework. It is a problem that is discussed online that may appear in online assessments. I've edited the question with the code I have. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about O(n^2) but this code gives the answer:

```py
def swapdigits(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    unique_pairs = []
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            str1 = str(arr[i])
            str2 = str(arr[j])
            if len(str1)==len(str2):
                if sorted(str1)==sorted(str2):
                    if len([None for i in range(len(str1)) if str1[i]!=str2[i]])==2:
                        unique_pairs.append((arr[i],arr[j],))
    return unique_pairs

arr = [3, 23, 156, 4324, 324, 651, 165, 32]
print(swapdigits(arr))
```

The logic of the code is to firstly get all the combinations and shortlist those combinations that have the same length, and then further shortlist those combinations that have the same letters and the same number of each letter, and then finally check for each combination if the pair differ only by two digits.